# PHP Parse Error: Unexpected $end (Line 410)

Tags: php

I have seen several questions on this topic, but I feel this one is different.

What I know/Googled: This is typically at the end of the file, which is error line I was given on my localhost.  I am using a WAMP server for my localhost development.  The code executes on the server without the errors.  The code executes on other's developers' computers with a different error that is probably JS related.  The page loads for them.

Solutions I've tried:

- Fresh code checkout in a new directory from SVN Repository: I had the same error, on the 
  same line (410).
- Bracket pairings in Notepad++:  I went through the code using the
  bracket highlighting feature, but found no unpaired brackets. #fail
- I pulled the file from the server, but still had the same error on my machine. #fail
- I added an endif(); call, but then I had an unexpected endif() error in place of the Unexpected $end.  #fail

Link to the code: https://www.box.com/s/09f39cb3c4afb0d93558 (Gist: https://gist.github.com/2795108 )

I think there may be an issue with my machine, but I can't figure out what it may be.  What other solutions are available?

Comment: Do both machines have the [`short_open_tag`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) option set identically?

Comment: Jeroen: It's on line 410.  DCoder: Where would I check that?  I always use <?php [code] ?>, so it's not something I ever thought about.  I've only been doing PHP development past three months, learning as I go.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer as I am not sure whether it matters. On the last bit of PHP it says "}?>" try putting a space between.

Comment: My suggestion: take a copy of the file, and strip out all the HTML code. Maybe leave stubs of code in there, but take out most of it. This will leave you with the same PHP code, but in a shorter file, which might make it easier to see what's happening.

Comment: FWIW running a syntax check (`php -l create.php`) on my machine gives "No syntax errors detected." OS X Lion/PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: You can check that setting with 'var_dump(ini_get('short_open_tag'));` - there's a short open tag in your gist, if your local installation has those turned off, that'll be the problem.

Comment: there is at least one short open tag, on line 260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to line 260 and replace `"<? } ?>"` by `"<?php } ?>"` , or create a .htaccess and add this line of code to activate short_open_tag : `php_flag short_open_tag on` . hope this was helpful )

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody.  The short tag was my problem.  Now I'm onto the next issue.